# Sound not working in VMware player

Tags: windows-7, linux, audio, linux-mint, vmware-player

Guest operating system is Windows 7 and I have VMware player 6.0.1 installed. On it latest version of Mint Linux is run. The problem is Linux never gets sound. How do I fix this? The message "the default sound device cannot be opened" is given in the Player.

I tried following [these instructions](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws3/doc/ws32_vidsound4.html) but the sound card is already there and the "connected" option is grayed out
[image: screen shot of VMware Player settings]

I also tried [these instructions](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003425) but can't find any `vmx` file however I can find a `vmxf` file.

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling VMware Player sometimes it could help.

Comment: Try updating VMware tools rather

Answer (score 1):

If `lspci|grep snd_ens1371` gives some output the sound kernel modules are loaded & sound is probably muted in `alsamixer`. Muted channels show up as 'MM' & can be **unmuted** by selecting them & pressing **M**.

If alsamixer does not detect a sound card run:

```
alsactl init
```

If you are using `pulseaudio` check `/etc/asound.conf`contains a minimum of:

```
pcm.pulse { type pulse }
ctl.pulse { type pulse }
pcm.!default { type pulse }
ctl.!default { type pulse }
```

I also changed the sound device settings in *VMWARE* to my detected speakers (from default host device).

Reboot & sound will work.

This fixed `xfce4-volume-control` / `gstreamer` complaining no sound card can be found & warning of a possible **permissions** problem. Trying to run just ALSA under Debian Wheezy 64 bit in *VMWARE* still gave this `gstreamer` error. *VMWARE* seems to run a little better with `pulseaudio` also being installed (sound in *Virtualbox* ran just fine with only ALSA).